# MySql to Postgres Data migration using Dapper tinyint to boolean

Tags: mysql, postgresql, .net-core, dapper

I am writing a dotnet core project to convert our production db to postgres from mysql.  Dapper seems to be converting a tinyint column to boolean when processing thru one table but about 2000 records in it is failing.  I did a quick console statement on Type and Value and am getting this:

A couple good records converting

`False
System.Boolean
True
System.Boolean`

The failed record

`1
System.SByte`

What would cause previous records to convert properly but not this one.  Upon quick inspection I do not see any reason why this row would behave any differently?  I can handle the case if needed but wondering why this would be happening? A quick distinct select in mysql only shows three records 0,1, and null Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example schema? What you've written here seems like internals, not something you can use in `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Note: MYSQL's "truthy" is really weird where boolean is concerned. If you're asking mysql to convert things to binary/boolean, 0=false, "0"= true, and other things that may or may not be similar in other languages/DB's

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like [Dapper issue 552](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/552): "Dapper fails on MySql nullable bool".

The underlying problem is [MySQL bug 78917](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78917), which is fixed in MySql.Data v6.10.8 and v8.0.12; updating the NuGet package to the latest version should resolve the problem.